# How to do Postcode to Addresses lookup using GetAddress.IO REST API in Salesforce

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, javascript, rest-api

Does anyone have any example Apex or Salesforce Lightning JavaScript code for doing a Postcode to Addresses lookup using the [getaddress.io](https://getaddress.io/) [REST API](https://getaddress.io/Documentation) within Salesforce Lightning?

Specifically how to performing a GET request to end point:

```
https://api.getAddress.io/find/{postcode}?api-key={api-key}
```

And handle the JSON response of:

```
{
    "latitude": 52.24593734741211,
    "longitude": -0.891636312007904,
    "addresses":["Line1,Line2,Line3,Line4,Locality,Town/City,County"]
}
```

As per their [documentation](https://getaddress.io/Documentation)

Either client-side Salesforce Lightning or Server-side Apex example code/classes would be great.

Comment: I've answered with my apex code in an attempt to be a good citzen and give back to the community, as per Joel Spolsky post: https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/05/22/encyclopedia-stack-exchange/ and the Salesforce Stack Exchange Help Center article 'Can I answer my own question?' https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer - where it seems we are being encouraged to contribute in this way...

Comment: I've added my vote to reopen. Note that in the review queue, only the question is shown by default, so it's not immediately clear that *you* are actually providing the sample code.

Comment: Does the quality of this question still warrant being 'on hold' ?

Comment: Honestly if it were just the question, this post would still be off topic. The answer redeems it, however.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've taken the server-side Apex approach to integrating with their REST API.

**Usage**

```
String postcode = 'NG16 2TH';
GetAddressAPI api = new GetAddressAPI()
String result = api.getAddresses(postcode);
```

**Apex**

```
public class GetAddressAPI {

    // Get Address API: https://getaddress.io/
    // Documentation: https://getaddress.io/Documentation

    public String getAddresses(String postcode) {

        if (postcode == null) {
            return null;
        }

        string responseData = makeAPICall(postcode);

        System.debug(responseData);

        if (responseData == null){
            return null;
        }

        LookupAddressResponse response = (LookupAddressResponse)JSON.deserialize(responseData, LookupAddressResponse.class);      

        List<LookupAddress> addresses = new List<LookupAddress>();

        for(string a : response.addresses){

            String[] segments = a.split(',');

            LookupAddress address = new LookupAddress();
            address.latitude = response.latitude;
            address.longitude = response.longitude;
            address.line1 = segments[0].trim();
            address.line2 = segments[1].trim();
            address.line3 = segments[2].trim();
            address.line4 = segments[3].trim();
            address.locality = segments[4].trim();
            address.townCity = segments[5].trim();
            address.county = segments[6].trim();
            address.postcode = postcode;

            String fullAddress = '';
            for (string segment : segments){
                if (String.isNotBlank(segment)){
                    if (fullAddress != ''){
                        fullAddress += ', ';
                    }
                    fullAddress += segment;
                }
            }
            fullAddress += ', ' + postcode;
            address.FullAddress = fullAddress;
            addresses.add(address);
        }

        return JSON.serialize(addresses);
    }

    public string makeAPICall(string postcode) {

        if (postcode == null) {
            return null;
        }        

        String url = 'https://api.getAddress.io/find/'
            + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(postcode.replace(' ', ''), 'UTF-8')
            + '?api-key=' + getAPIKey();

        Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        HttpResponse httpResponse = new HttpResponse();
        request.setMethod('GET');
        request.setEndpoint(url);
        request.setTimeout(120000);
        httpResponse = http.send(request); 

        if (httpResponse.getStatusCode() == 200){
            return httpResponse.getBody();    
        } else {
            System.debug(httpResponse.getStatusCode());
            System.debug(httpResponse.getBody());
            throw new AuraHandledException(httpResponse.getBody());
        }        
    }

    private String getAPIKey() {
        return ''; // Add your API key or get it from custom settings
    }

    class LookupAddressResponse {
        Decimal latitude;
        Decimal longitude;
        List<String> addresses;
    }

    class LookupAddress {
        Decimal latitude;
        Decimal longitude;
        String fullAddress;
        String line1;
        String line2;
        String line3;
        String line4;
        String locality;
        String townCity;
        String county;
        String postcode;
    }
}
```